# In Node JS how to return last insert id when am inserting data into multiple tables (using sequlize for inserting data into mysql)?

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

1. I have to insert data into 2 tables (i.e. **`Candidate`** and **`Project`**).
2. In the "add candidate" form there is a dropdown for project (data for project is fetched from project master table), there is an option where they can select 'OTHER', when other is selected in dropdown of project field a new textbox will appear where they can enter the project name.
3. When the form is submitted, first I want to store the new project name in PROJECT MASTER TABLE, so that i can get the last insert id from PROJECT MASTER.
4. Second store the information of candidate in CANDIDATE TABLE with `project_id` (which will be last insert `id` of PROJECT MASTER TABLE).

How can I achieve this?

```js
 let project_id=req.body.project;
 
 if(req.body.project=='other'){
 //project table columns
 let projects = {
          name: req.body.project_name,
          status: 1,
          created_by: req.user.user_id,
          createdAt: getCurrentDatetime(),
        };
  
  Project.create(projects).then((data) => {
         project_id=data.id;
    });
  }
  
 
//candidate table columns
let candidate = {
    first_name: req.body.firstname,
    last_name: req.body.lastname,
    project_id: project_id,
    createdAt: getCurrentDatetime(),
    updatedAt: getCurrentDatetime(),
  };
  
  Candidate.create(candidate)
    .then((data) => {
    if(data){
    console.log('inserted'):
    
    }
    });
```

This code is giving me error, its only inserting project data in PROJECT MASTER table, but during candidate insertion its storing 0 in project_id.

Answer (score 0):

You *write* a value to `project_id` *asynchronously* in the callback function, this is executed only after the insertion into the project master table has completed. But you *read* the value from `project_id` *synchronously*, immediately after starting the insertion into the project master table (but before it has completed). Effectively, you read the value before you write it.

The following code makes use of a promise `p` that resolves to the project ID, which is determined either from the insertion result or from `req.body` directly:

```js
let p;
if (req.body.project=='other') {
  let projects = {...};
  p = Project.create(projects).then(data => data.id);
} else
  p = Promise.resolve(req.body.project);
p.then(function(project_id) {
  let candidate = {...};
  Candidate.create(candidate)
    .then((data) => {...});
});
```